error in grails when i do .\gradle bootRun
I have installed grails 6.2 on my windows machine.
  D:\sc>grails --version
  Grails Version: 6.2.2
  JVM Version: 17.0.13
  D:\sc>

When I try to run .\gradlew\bootRun I get:
  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

  * Where:
  Build file 'D:\sc\build.gradle' line: 14

  * What went wrong:
  Plugin [id: 'com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries', version: '3.2'] was not found in any of 
  the following sources:

  - Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
  - Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.github.erdi.webdriver- 
  binaries:com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries.gradle.plugin:3.2')
    Searched in the following repositories:
      Gradle Central Plugin Repository

  * Try:
  > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
  > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. 
  > Run with --scan to get full insights.

  * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

  BUILD FAILED in 8s

This line where it complains is
id "com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries" version "3.2"
What could be the problem?

Here is an example from a demo project generated on start.grails.org, which is not seeing this issue.
build.gradle
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo.grails.org/grails/core" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies { // Not Published to Gradle Plugin Portal
        classpath "org.grails:grails-gradle-plugin:6.2.3"
        classpath "org.grails.plugins:hibernate5:8.1.0"
    }
}

plugins {
    id "groovy"
    id "com.github.erdi.webdriver-binaries" version "3.2"
    id "war"
    id "idea"
    id "com.bertramlabs.asset-pipeline" version "4.5.1"
    id "application"
    id "eclipse"
}

// Not Published to Gradle Plugin Portal
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-web"
apply plugin: "org.grails.grails-gsp"

